# try / except not catching string inputs as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

Although I am using try except blocks in factorial for `str` inputs, but I am getting value error with `int(input)`, when I enter a `str`.

```
def fact(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        try:
            x * fact(x-1)
        except TypeError:
            print('factorial of strings cannot be calculated!')

    elif x == 0 :
        return 1
    
    elif x < 0:
        print('factorial of a Negative Number cannot be calculated!')
        
    else:
        return x * fact(x-1)
    
 #--------------------------------------------------------

while True:
    x = int(input('Enter X: '))
    print(fact(x))
```

Comment: When I enter a string like ``abc`` a `ValueError` occurs, not a `TypeError`. The error is `x = int(input('Enter X: '))` → `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'` so you need a `try` / `except` there.

Comment: `if isinstance(x, str)` In this case you _already_ know it's a string, so why even bother with the try block?

Answer (score 3):

The exception is being raised by `int` before `fact` is ever called. You need to catch the exception when it occurs. (As such, it's not really worth doing this type of run-time error checking in `fact`: document that `fact` requires an `int` as an argument, and let the caller face the consequences of passing some other type.)

```
def fact(x):
    if x == 0 :
        return 1
    
    elif x < 0:
        raise ValueError('factorial of a Negative Number cannot be calculated!')
        
    else:
        return x * fact(x-1)
    
 #--------------------------------------------------------

while True:
    try:
        x = int(input('Enter X: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Input was not a valid int, try again")
        continue
    print(fact(x))
```

Comment: to make the program to be continued, can we write 
elif x < 0:
        print('factorial of a Negative Number cannot be calculated!')
Because the way you have written the code, if we enter negative number, the program stops.

Comment: That's intentional. It's not the job of `fact` to decide what to do if the caller passed an invalid argument. Raise the exception, and let the caller decide how to handle the error.

Comment: Thabk you so much  for your help 